# TypeScript definitions in WebStorm

Tags: typescript, webstorm, typescript-typings

I have installed the `Q` library trought NPM. After that I have downloaded d.ts file trought `JavaScript->Libraries` menu. But `import`  couldn't find it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

External libraries work only for flat JavaScript. Instead it we need to use `typings` or another managers.